# Boost.Asio, two readings by the same socket

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I'm learning Boost.Asio. I have defined a class that has the role of client and server:

- I can create connections, send requests and receive responses (client role).
- I can accept requests and send responses to those requests (server role).
- I can also create subscriptions: Creates a connection, it sends a subscription request and waits for the response. If the remote endpoint accepts the request, it will send me regularly data by this connection.

I want to be able to make requests and receive responses after a subscription, but there is a problem when I get the response: at that moment the socket waiting at the same time receive a subscription and a response.

Sometimes there is deadlock, sometimes I get a subscription when it was waiting for a response, ...

To read, I use the following functions:

```
void async_receive_subscription(const socket& the_socket, read_handler_signature handler)
{
    auto self( this->shared_from_this() );

    boost::asio::async_read(
        the_socket.get(),
        boost::asio::buffer( my_buffer ),
        [this, self, the_socket, my_buffer, handler]
        ( const boost::system::error_code& error,
          std::size_t bytes_transferred )
        {
            the_socket.get().get_io_service().post(
                std::bind(
                handler,
                error,
                bytes_transferred,
                the_socket,
                my_buffer
                )
            );
            // Read the next subscription.
            async_receive_subscription(the_socket, handler);
        }
    );
}

void async_receive(const socket& the_socket, read_handler_signature handler)
{
    auto self( this->shared_from_this() );

    boost::asio::async_read(
        the_socket.get(),
        boost::asio::buffer( my_buffer ),
        [this, self, the_socket, my_buffer, handler]
        ( const boost::system::error_code& error,
          std::size_t bytes_transferred )
        {
            the_socket.get().get_io_service().post(
                std::bind(
                handler,
                error,
                bytes_transferred,
                the_socket,
                my_buffer
                )
            );
        }
    );
}
```

Is it possible to expect two responses by the same socket? Is there any synchronization mechanism that can be used to avoid this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of `the_socket` and are you doing tcp or udp? (assuming tcp). Existing answer is likely it though

Comment: Yes, the socket is TCP. It's a shared pointer to boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket.

Comment: I asked because `the_socket.get().get_io_service()` is not a valid expression for the shared pointer

Comment: Yes, in fact it is a wrapper of `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket`. Internally defines the shared pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

async_read is guaranteed to cause exactly one call of the handler.

You must not call async_read again until this handler has been called.

question:

1. are you running the io_service in multiple threads? If so, you'll need to pass your handler through an asio::strand.

Comment: I've updated the function. In the handler, I am invoking back to the function.  Should I invoke the function when the io_service run the handler?

Comment: In the handler, the user defines the message protocol that he want to use and apply the synchronization mechanisms in order to use multiple threads. For this reason, I don't want to use `asio::strand`.

Comment: Bad idea. If you want to do that, hand off the handler to the user's thread so he can't cause synchronisation problems for himself or you

Comment: Ok, I have a bad design.

Comment: This answer is correct, I recommend you use a different port for subscriptions. An alternative is to build a protocol that has function codes like SUBSCRIPTION, REQUEST, RESPONSE etc so you can just read and then treat the packets differently based on that code.